# Dynamically Add Widget on user click in Gmail Add-on using CardService Appscript (GAS)

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am working on creating Gmail Add-on on one of my project. I got stuck on one scenario. I want to show user a dropdown and when user selects any value from this dropdown, I want to dynamically add a new label/texfield below dropdown which will show you the selected value. 
I am using newSelectionInput method of CardService to create a dropdown.
Here's the code for it:

```
var dueDateDropDown = CardService.newSelectionInput()
.setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
.setTitle("Due Date")
.setFieldName("due_date")
.addItem("No due date", "one_value", true)
.addItem("Today", "two_value", false)
.addItem("Tomorrow", "three_value", false)
.addItem("This Friday", "four_value", false)
.addItem("Next Monday", "five_value", false)
.setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('addLabel'))
```

So can someone help me writing the `addLabel` function which will add label widget. 
This is a function which I am trying to write:

```
 function addLabel(e){
  var selected = e.formInputs.due_date;

  // Activate temporary Gmail add-on scopes.
  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

  var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
  var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
  var thread = message.getThread();

  Logger.log(message.getSubject());
  Logger.log(selected);
  // What should be the code for adding a label or textbox to the widget here.
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To manipulate the UI requires building a CardService card and adding it to the navigation stack.

Comment: @tehhowch Can you suggest me some example which I can refer to. Thanks!

Comment: I have the similar issue with `TestButton` and `setDisabled` function. If I want to disable/enable button, I need to rebuild the whole UI.

Comment: @Niko yes currently there is no way in Gmail addon to update only particular section. We have to re-build the whole card again :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by re-building the UI.

```
function buildAddOn(e){
  return buildUi(e);  
}


function buildUi(e,labelData){

  var dueDateDropDown = CardService.newSelectionInput()
  .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
  .setTitle("Due Date")
  .setFieldName("due_date")
  .addItem("No due date", "one_value", true)
  .addItem("Today", "two_value", false)
  .addItem("Tomorrow", "three_value", false)
  .addItem("This Friday", "four_value", false)
  .addItem("Next Monday", "five_value", false)
  .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('addLabel'))

   var section = CardService.newCardSection();   
  section.addWidget(dueDateDropDown);

  if(labelData){
     var label = CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(labelData);
    section.addWidget(label);
  }
 // e.somedata = true;
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
  .addSection(section)
  .build();


  return card; 

}

function addLabel(e){
  Logger.log(e);
  var selected = e.formInputs.due_date.toString();
  return buildUi(e,selected);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sunil , thanks for sharing this snippet. I'm upvoting it but still I am looking for another approach where we don't have to re-build the entire UI because in a card there are many sections and widgets , so it will increase the UI response time and may not look so user friendly.

Comment: I was able to get this to work on a fairly complex UI card I am designing. There are two things that I can't seem to control:<br>
1) The DueDate selector after `OnChangeAction` reverts to the default `No due date`, so the user looses the context of their selection.<br>
2) There is no way to setup that the default value of `No due date` to force an  `OnChangeAction` event to push the `"one_value"` `label` to the UI.<br>
<br>
Anyone able to use this to accomplish the above?

Comment: Created a new question for above^
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69365524/control-onchangeaction-default-and-revert-to-default-when-dynamically-adding-wid/69409427#69409427