# Control OnChangeAction default and revert to default when dynamically adding Widget to Google Add-on card

Tags: google-apps-script

Starting a new question to extend [Dynamically Add Widget on user click in Gmail Add-on using CardService Appscript (GAS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931400/dynamically-add-widget-on-user-click-in-gmail-add-on-using-cardservice-appscript/53979111#53979111)

I was able to get this to work on a fairly complex UI card I am designing.

There are two things that I can't seem to control:

1. The selector after OnChangeAction reverts to the default item, so the user looses the context of their selection. Is there a way to persist the selection when rebuilding the card?
2. There is no way to setup that the value of the default selected item to force an OnChangeAction event to push its value to the UI on the cards initial load.

Anyone able to use this method to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a hack for this that seems to work.

I added a default item to the top of the item list with a label of `item0`

`.addItem("Click here to select an existing item to edit","item0", true)`

I also created a cache to cache this label. `CacheService.getUserCache().put('itemSelected','item0')`

When the item is selected from the dropdown I update the Cache with that items value, e.g. `item(n)`.

I then set up two Widgets within a single function `itemManagerCard(e, item)` that takes the item I want to change as a parameter.

WidgetOne is the base state of the card where the parameters are `undefined`

`if(item === undefined)`

WidgetTwo responds when `onModeChange(e)` returns the target card with the `item` parameters I want to change

`return itemManagerCard(e, item);`

`if(item != undefined)`

I can then populate WidgetTwo with whatever UI data I want to collect through the function's parameters. Such as:

`var editItemNumText = 'You are currently editing ${itemNum}'`

```js
    function itemManagerCard(e, item) {
    
    var selectItemBodyWidget = CardService.newSelectionInput()
        .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
        .setTitle('Which item do you want to edit?')
        .setFieldName('editItem');
        .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('onModeChange'))
        .addItem("Click here to select an existing Item to edit","item0", true)
        .addItem("Item 1","item1", false);
//

   if (item != undefined)
     let itemNum = CacheService.getUserCache().get('itemNum');
     var itemText = `You are currently editing ${itemNum}`;
     var itemWidget = CardService.newTextParagraph()
          .setText(itemText);
}


  function onModeChange(e) {
    let itemNum = (e.formInput.editItem);
    CacheService.getUserCache().put('itemNum', itemNum);
    var item = itemArr[itemNum]
    return itemManagerCard(e, item);
}
```

Major drawback is needing to build and maintain the two separate virtually identical Widgets, which can get messy the more complex it gets.